# Expected Semi Colon

Tags: php

```
<?php
    'doctrine' => [
        'meta' => [
            'entity_path' => [
                'app/src/Entity'
            ],
            'auto_generate_proxies' => true,
            'proxy_dir' =>  __DIR__.'/../cache/proxies',
            'cache' => null,
        ],
        'connection' => [
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'dbname'   => 'sano',
            'user'     => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
        ]
    ]
```

I have php file above. Error occure second line Expected Semi Colon.
How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: you should give it a name..since you are using key=>value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name=array(
        'doctrine' => [
            'meta' => [
                'entity_path' => [
                    'app/src/Entity'
                ],
                'auto_generate_proxies' => true,
                'proxy_dir' =>  __DIR__.'/../cache/proxies',
                'cache' => null,
            ],
            'connection' => [
                'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'dbname'   => 'sano',
                'user'     => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

where `$name` is replaced by the variable name